# Why is it a Bad Idea To Allow Any IP Address to Access My EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2, service

Why is it a bad idea to allow any IP address to access my EC2 instance in group securities and what would I do to avoid this, how would a user access the EC2 server if for instance it was running a nodejs webapp on it?

Comment: It's good to reduce your [attack surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface).

Comment: Also cost. This will help reduce the amount of traffic that you will need to pay for.

Comment: lol i get down voted for asking a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously for a lot of use cases, you are going to have to allow any IP address to connect to it - for example, if you are running a public website you would allow traffic from any IP address to ports 80 (and 443 if SSL).

What you don't want to do is allow traffic from any IP to ports that nobody else has business using - for example if you were running SQL Server on it, you wouldn't want to allow world-wide access to port 1433.

If you do, I guarantee you that within a short amount of time you will see in your logs ten's of thousands of attempts to login to your server - they will run 24x7x365 trying passwords to get in - this is true of any service on any port, so that is why you want to completely block ports that are not used at all, and only allow traffic from known ip addresses for users that have a need to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I only allow connections for HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) via iptables.

You can add SSH (port 22) access for your own IP only.

I do with with a initialization script, but there's probably also a way to do it via the Amazon Web Form for security groups.

```
#! /bin/sh

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```